# Having problems with gulp-uglify

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs, uglifyjs

I'm having some serious trouble getting gulp-uglify to minify my files.

Here is my gulpfile.

```
var gulp       = require('gulp');
var gutil      = require('gulp-util');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify   = require('babelify');
var source     = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer     = require('vinyl-buffer');
var uglify     = require('gulp-uglify');
var size       = require('gulp-size');

gulp.task('scripts', function () {

  var bundler = browserify({
    entries: ['views/main.js'],
    debug: true,
  })
  .transform(babelify, { presets: ['react', 'es2015'] });

  bundler.bundle()
      .pipe(source('main.js'))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['scripts']);
```

Using `gutil`, I found the line giving gulp-uglify the error, which is very confusing:

```
{ [Error: /Users/fzxt/Documents/Web/Chatr/main.js: Unexpected token: keyword (const)]
  message: '/Users/fzxt/Documents/Web/Chatr/main.js: Unexpected token: keyword (const)',
  fileName: '/Users/fzxt/Documents/Web/Chatr/main.js',
  lineNumber: 66598..
```

It's having trouble with the keyword `const` which is odd because I'm transforming the bundler with `babelify` before I give it to `uglify`. I've also put the presets as well.

Could anyone help me out on how to deal with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using vanilla browserify, you will need to do it like this:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var babelify = require('babelify');
var transform = require('vinyl-transform');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
  var browserified = transform(function(filename) {
    var b = browserify({
      entries: filename,
      debug: true,
      transform: [
        [babelify, {
          presets: ['react', 'es2015']
        }]
      ]
    });
    return b.bundle();
  });
  
  return gulp.src(['views/main.js'])
    .pipe(browserified)
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```